# Azure Function works locally - doesn't when deployed

Tags: azure-functions

I've created a basic HTTP Trigger function (Python based).
It works when debugged locally in VS Code.
When deploying to an Azure Function App the deployment is successful, but when you go to .scm.azurewebsites.net only the host.json shows and not the functionname/init.py / function.json or assetsfolder/... show in the wwwroot.
Has anyone seen / fixed this before?

Thanks,
Dan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Published the Azure Functions Python Version 3.9 HTTP Trigger Project to the Azure Function App from Visual Studio Code**:

[image]

[image]

I can see the `code file`, `function.json` file in **Code + Test** menu of the Azure Function App > Function:
[image]

- Changed the content of the HTTP Trigger Functions and added the `WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE` setting in Azure Function App Application settings under configuration.
- Published the Function again to the same function app.
  Still, I too didn't see the files except `host.json`.

I guess this is a feature request because for other stacks like .NET, files are visible.

Please raise a feature request in the [GitHub Kudu Issues Repo](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/issues) for quick resolution.